# Any ideas on copying this voice effect?

Tags: sound-effects, audacity, adobe-audition

### Trying to copy the effects from this video:

mainly the ones at:

- **0:30 - 0:40**
- **2:12 - 2:42**
- **5:31 - 5:47**

---

I'm only really able to use `Audacity` and `Adobe Audition` so answers with that in mind would be greatly appreciated

I've tried many different variations using echo, delay, reverb and chorus mixed those effects together. Also I used multiple different tracks with tuning volume to control when the echos or delayed voices fade in or out.

So far no luck. Any advice you can offer would be a huge help.

What should I do to reproduce the effect from the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the three clips you call out, the only effect I hear is a slight reverse reverb or pre-echo.  In your audio editor, select the audio you want to process and reverse it so it plays backwards.  Then apply a short reverb effect.  Don’t go crazy here; a little goes a long way.  Then re-reverse the audio so the reverb tails fade in before each word.

It’ll probably take a few tries to find settings that sound good, but to match the sample clips, set the reverb decay time at ~300 ms or so and effect level at 20% and fine tune from there.  You can also try an echo effect instead of reverb with the same time and level settings as above and no feedback.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try ! :)